# Trying to add a field to Django many-to-many relation

Tags: python, django, django-models

Right now I'm working on a Django project responsible for the warehouse management system.
I got products, customers, warehouse branches, product types, orders, etc...
products can be [Milk 1L bottle, cheese 500g pack, ....]
The problem I have been facing is that I'm trying to make a many-to-many relationship between orders and products so I can track the products sold in each order. **Yet, I want to add the 'quantity' column to that table created by many-to-many** because a customer can order 5 cheese packs and 2 milk bottles.
I know that I can add 'ManyToManyField.through' but it takes a string for a model as args and that's what I don't want.

I wish to easily have an extra IntegerField called quantity.

## Here's how I wish my table to look-like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ9MU.png)

Comment: Why don't you add a price field in the Product model and based on quantity multiply the price to get the total cost of that product. In Order model show the total price by adding all the costs of each product.

Comment: An Order can contain more than one product, as I said it could be [5 cheese packs and 2 milk bottles] so the total amount won't get me quantity alone.  I maintain the price in another table to track history as it changes.

Comment: How do you which product cost how much with that DB design? without having prize field in product model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use these models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = ...


class Order(models.Model):
    user = ...
    address = ...

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,...)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,...)
    quantity= ...
```

Now your customers can have many order items with products in each order.

Comment: That's a great answer that worked fine. I thought I can get a better way rather than a pivot table yet I will use that until any further updates.